# inner join without unique identifier

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

On the screenshot below you see two tables. On the left side I have a table with accidents, in this case the ID is unique and it is always the same accident with ID=68.

On the right side is the weather data available with the temperature of the specific day.

However, the date is not uniquely identifiable since there exists five Saturday's in January in my case.
What I am trying to do, is to write the temperature in my first "Accident" table (empty column).

I know that there is a problem since I don't want to have five times the same accident in my table (id=68 should remain uniquely).
Is there a way to join this data even if the temperature will not be 100% correct? I am happy with an average of the temperature, or just use the first entry.

This is my query, it never stops to run.

```
UPDATE accident_copy as a
LEFT JOIN wetterdaten as w
ON a.year = w.year
    and a.monthDE = w.month
    and a.day = w.day
    and a.hour = w.hour
SET a.Temperatur = w.Temperatur;
```

[image]

Comment: I only see one table in the screen shot. Can you be more specific? Also, please provide the expected result.

Comment: Why are you satisfied with incorrect data? Is there a day column? Or date and time? In both tables?

Comment: @TheImpaler In the screenshot I selected both tables.

Comment: @SalmanA I don't need it for professional purposes, only for study purposes. Therefore, the correctness is not of great importance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead use a subquery to get your average temperature for that time:

```
UPDATE accident_copy as a
LEFT JOIN 
   (
      SELECT avg(temperatur) temparatur, year, month, day, hour 
      FROM wetterdaten
      GROUP BY year, month, day, hour
    ) as w
ON a.year = w.year
    and a.monthDE = w.month
    and a.day = w.day
    and a.hour = w.hour
SET a.Temperatur = w.Temperatur;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It never ends to run. Any hint?

Comment: Apologies. I forgot the GROUP BY. Updated the answeer.

Comment: Just to let you know, there is a comma missing after "day" when you group it.